# Reopen request for question 384894

Tags: support, status-declined, reopen-request

I asked this: [Is a 'telecommuter' SLA a good idea? Does it even exist?](https://superuser.com/questions/384894/is-a-telecommuter-sla-a-good-idea-does-it-even-exist)

I don't know where else on StackExchange to ask other than SuperUser. This clearly falls under the general SuperUser description of "Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users" and in the [faq](https://superuser.com/faq) with "personal and home computer networking".

I edited the original question so that I can get educated about SLAs as they apply to telecommuting rather than asking for specific ISPs.

I got some good answers to this question too!

Comment: You're not asking about the technology that enables high reliability (and in that case, it'd probably be more a Server Fault topic). Your question is purely about the business/legal side, and therefore just as off topic as software licensing questions. I also stand by my decision.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note that

> I got some good answers to this question too!

and

> Q&A for computer enthusiasts and power users

do not conclude that a question is on topic. You can get answers for any question here, if people are willing to answer them, and just because you're a computer enthusiast, well, that doesn't make a question about Service Level Agreements with ISPs on-topic on a site that deals primarily with:

- personal computer hardware
- computer software

Your question is purely about business contracts, possibly even localized to some ISP providers in your area. It only marginally covers the topics we deal with on Super User. I still stand by my decision and therefore won't vote to reopen.